# Pandas giving each set of 2 values in a row a unique number starting from 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm

I have 2 columns in my pandas dataframe: 'a' and 'b', and I need to add 3rd column called 'no' to my df which gives a number to a pair starting from 1, if the values are the same (they can be in different order), and each time it meets new pair (the one where at least one value is unseen) it should increment. If the pair has no other occurencies, it should also increment by 1:

```
example
a    b    no
1    2    1
4    3    2
2    1    1
3    4    2
5    6    3
4    7    4
```

I've written a code which works fine, but I'm searching for a faster and shorter solution

```
l = []
n = 1
nums = {}
for a, b in zip(df.a, df.b):
    s = str(sorted([a, b]))
    if s in nums.keys():
        l.append(nums[s])
    else:
        nums[s] = n
        l.append(n)
        n += 1
df['no'] = l
```

Comment: Something is not entirely clear: 
Do you want your ['no'] column to be reset to 1: if you encounter a pair (in whatever order) that has already been encountered, or if all of the numbers in the pair have been already encountered (maybe also in different pairs)?

Also, the 'already been encountered' mechanism should be valid from the start of the dataframe, or from the previous row where `['no'] = 1` (so basically it resets every time there is a row with `['no'] = 1`)?

Comment: Also, for example, what would be your ['no'] column for your df if `a = [1,4,2,3,5,4,4,8,1]`, `b = [2,3,1,4,6,7,4,1,8]`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the code should work as a hashmap (if I understand it correctly), so if I meet a set of values that has already been met, I need to put in 'no' a value for it (the key is a pair itself) from the dict. If not - I put it in a dict, and the value is n+1. The start value is n = 1. This is what my code basically does, I just wander if I can solve it in a shorter (and faster) way

Comment: It should be 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 6

Comment: ok, then why it has to be `1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 6` (as it is for your code)? 
When should the ['no'] number be repeated (stay the same number) like in the last 2 digits here? The pairs for those `6` are `8,1` and `1,8`. It seems to me that is the same pair (even though different order), so shouldn't it start back from 1? -->  `1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 1`?

Comment: Ok I get it now, the number is the hash key given to a set pair! 
Alright!

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
s = df.apply(frozenset, axis=1)
df.assign(no=pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1)
```

output:

```
    a   b   no
0   1   2   1
1   4   3   2
2   2   1   1
3   3   4   2
4   5   6   3
5   4   7   4
```

**intermediate**

s

```
0    (1, 2)
1    (3, 4)
2    (1, 2)
3    (3, 4)
4    (5, 6)
5    (4, 7)
dtype: object
```